# jQuery DataTables: calling draw() inside initComplete

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

So, for my datatable, I need to do some ajax calls and redraw the table with the returned info, but I had some... problems.

I tried to do the ajax calls inside the Datatable event "drawCallback", and call the function *draw*() when the calls completed, but, on execution, the event was firing endlessly until the browser crashed. I guess it is because the event "drawCallback" is fired after calling *draw()* (it seems obvious for me now, but I didn't realise it when I was coding it).

So, my question is, if I try to do the same ajax calls (and posterior *draw()* calls) inside the event "initComplete", instead of using "drawCallback", will the *draw()* function fire the event "initComplete" again? (and resulting in an endless loop again)

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention I'm using a Java Servlet as server, where the ajax calls are directed. Here is the Datatable code:

*(yes, I'm using scriptlets here, I'm a monster)*

```
$("#dtExample").DataTable({
    data: <%= lGastosJson %>,
    columns: [
        {data: 'idGasto'},
        {data: 'fecha'},
        {data: 'descripcion'},
        {data: 'projectDescription'},
        {data: 'descrTipoGasto'},
        {data: 'costoTotalEuro'},
        {data: 'nombreAdjunto',
        defaultContent: ''}
    ],
    columnDefs: [
        // ...
    ],
    drawCallback: function(settings){
        var tableData = this.api().rows().data();
        var redraw = false;
        var self = this;

        for (var i=0;i<tableData.length;i++){
        //This column may be empty, I'm only doing the ajax call if it is NOT empty
        if (typeof tableData[i]['nombreAdjunto'] !== 'undefined'){
             var output = "";

            $.ajax({
                url: '<%= contextPath %>/AsincronasServlet',
                data: {command: "getAttachPhotos", username: "<%= user %>", adjunto: tableData[i]['nombreAdjunto'], index: i},
                success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
                var resultParams = result.split("@");
                var error = false;
                var index = -1;
                for (var j=0; j<resultParams.length; j++){
                    if (resultParams[j].substring(0,5) === "error"){
                        error = true;
                    }
                    if (resultParams[j].substring(0,5) === "index"){    //el indice se necesita tanto en success como en error
                        var idxPar = resultParams[j].split(":");
                        index = idxPar[1];
                    }
                }

                //The idea is using this if-else to change the inner HTML of the column and then redraw
                if (error){
                    output = "<span class='fa fa-search fa-2x previewError' aria-hidden='true' title='Error al cargar la imagen'></span>";
                    tableData[index]['nombreAdjunto'] = output;
                } else {
                    //haven't coded this yet                        
                }

                self.api().rows().draw();
            }
        });
     }
 }}});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "*but, on execution, the event was firing endlessly until the browser crashed*" A true stack overflow :). You use the draw callback to update the table which calls the draw callback which updates the table and so on...  Besides that not particular answerable without some code - what are you trying to do, exactly ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you do the manipulation upfront, not after table initialisation. You can pass a function to data, and in that function run the AJAX loop.  Very schematic, no way I can reproduce your code :

```js
function dataCallback(tableData) {
  for (var i=0;i<tableData.length;i++){
    ...
    ...
    if (i == tableData.length-1) {
      return tableData
    }
  }
}
```

in the dataTable initialisation :

```js
data: dataCallback(<%= lGastosJson %>),
```

Proof of concept, data can be manipulated this way -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/960/**

Comment: I like this approach, it reduces the number of draws the table executes. Sadly, it doesn't work for my case. Since I'm updating the info with AJAX, and in most cases I'll need to do more than one call, I can't return the data in the AJAX succes function.
Anyway, your answer is very useful, as it's far cleaner to modify the content before the first draw than doing it after fully drawing it and having to redraw again. Thanks! :D

Comment: @Paul, thats why I suggested `if (i == tableData.length-1) {`, you cannot return from ajax success, but you can return from the `for (var i=0;i<tableData.length;i++){` loop when last cycle has finished. Perhaps also add a small timeout before exiting.

Comment: Instead of adding a small timeout, wouldn't it be easier to setting the ajax calls to async=false?

Comment: @Paul, I believe `async: false` is more or less dead or deprecated.  Also it block anything else as well. The timeout was just if you have really slow AJAX calls or preprocessing, and are in risk of have reached the end of the loop without all processing have finished. Alternatively you can use `$q` or `jQuery.Deferred()` if you want to be absolutely sure. But try first if it not works without all that, I could imagine you not have need of it at all.

Comment: The Deferred option seems a good one. I'll try that. Thanks for your help! :D